# Can I make a rich text box display control pictures?

Tags: .net, unicode, fonts, richtextbox

I'm trying to display [control pictures](http://www.alanwood.net/unicode/control_pictures.html) in a rich text box. I need the textbox to remain monospaced.

When I copy-paste said characters into Visual Studio, they appear monospaced and just fine. But when being displayed in the rich text box, they're just squares. Both my IDE and text box are using Consolas.

I see this in my IDE (the last two characters are equivalent):

```
richtextbox.Text = new string(new[] {'→', '␣', '␂', '\u2402'});
```

But my text box display the first two characters, then two boxes:

[image: →␣␂␂]

How can I get the full character picture to display?

Comment: How are you getting those characters into the rich text box? Copy paste? Thru code?

Comment: @JoelLucsy I'm building a string via `StringBuilder` then setting the text through code.

Comment: Ok. Paste the code here so we can see. Otherwise we'll be guessing.

Comment: @JoelLucsy It's pretty trivial code, but added anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are very few fonts in Windows that contain a large number of oddball characters from the Unicode character set. When I paste one of your control characters into Word, it converts it to the Arial Unicode MS font which appears to be the backup for characters that aren't available in a font.

Try setting the font in the Rich Edit to Arial Unicode MS before you insert the character.

Comment: Do you know if this is how Visual Studio displays them when pasted into the IDE?

Comment: @DanRasmussen, I know that some applications will use a substitute font automatically, the process might even be built into parts of the Windows API. I don't know specifically what Visual Studio does.

Comment: Is there any way to force character width to keep the text box monospace when doing this?

Comment: @DanRasmussen, all of the control characters should be the same width, and Microsoft might have designed them to blend in with a monospace font. Try it and see.

Answer (score 1):

With the given requirements, it seems that the only font you can use is [Everson Mono](http://www.evertype.com/emono/). For example, the character U+2402 is contained in a handful of fonts only, according to [font coverage information at Fileformat.info](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2402/fontsupport.htm), and Everson Mono (together with Everson Mono Oblique) seems to be the only monospace font among them.

Using a mixture of fonts, e.g. Consolas for all characters that it covers and some other monospace font(s), will generally not work: it will break the monospace property of text. (Different monospace fonts in the same font size need not have equal advance width, and they mostly don’t.)

Comment: I tried that. Unfortunately, Visual Studio complains that only TrueType Fonts can be used when trying to set the Font through the designer. Perhaps this is a designer issue and it can be set programatically.